# is subsumption inference possible in traditional database systems (RDBMS)?

Tags: database, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, triplestore

My question is about subsumption in databases (versus ontologies). My understanding says that if I have instances that belong to Class B, then Class A which is the superclass of Class B will also have these instances.

Ontologies provide in-built subsumption inference through the various reasoners (e.g. RDFS++, Pellet, etc.). I would like to know if it is possible to achieve a similar task in database systems. If so, how flexible or easy is it to implement? Are there any advantages of the database implementation (if any) over the ontology-based approach?

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, an ontology doesn't perform reasoning. An ontology is the set of logical axioms that a reasoner uses to answer queries with the inferred (and explicit) information in your knowledge base.

There are a number of existing open-source and commercial systems which perform reasoning and could be considered a database as opposed to something that is purely for reasoning, like Pellet/Fact/Hermit. Examples include AllegroGraph, GraphDb, and Stardog. So obviously, yes, it's possible. There are a couple different ways to approach the implementation, so you have some flexility on how to design the system based on your preferred use case.

It's not hard to create a toy reasoner that will parse an ontology and do some basic reasoning like subsumption. But if you want to support (correctly) one of the OWL fragments, and you want to do it at scale, it's not easy.

Go look at how Jena and its reasoners are implemented, that will be enough to get you going.

Sesame also has a RDFS reasoner, so that would be another source for you to review.